# Need two action in chrome extension browser action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create one chrome extension with content script interaction. I am facing one problem in the browser action scenario. I have tried to search the solution in the google but vain.

Here is the scenario.

I want two different action when click on the chrome extension icon (browser action). If i have some key stored in local storage, i need to send a message to content script else i need to show popup.

Say for an example, if suppose i am trying to validate whether user is logged in gmail or not. At first time if user didn't logged in i need to show popup with message "please log in" when click on the extension icon. If user already logged in then i will store it in local storage, so if user click again in the icon instead of showing popup need to contact content script.

Please suggest.

EDIT : UPDATING MY CODE HERE

in background.js. (problem is it is not going into the else part. always its showing popup eventhough it has local storage value)

```
if(localStorage.accessToken=="" || localStorage.accessToken==undefined){
      chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
            popup : "popup.html"
       })
}else{
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(e){
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},function(tabs)
        {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{accesskey:localStorage.accessToken},function(response) {});
        });
    })
    console.log('already logged in')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The browserAction.onClicked event does not fire when it already has a popup.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you need help with here so I'm guessing based on the wording of your question that you need help with either logic or localStorage.

I don't know a ton about events on the chrome extension icon, but assuming that you can get that event your code ought to look something like the following:

```
// this code goes inside your icon click handler
if (localStorage.loggedIn === 'loggedIn') {
    // do whatever action you want to happen if the user is logged in
} else {
    if (/* check to see if logged in goes here*/) {
        // user is logged in so store value so you don't have to check again
        localStorage.loggedIn = 'loggedIn';
    } else {
        localStorage.clear('loggedIn');
        alert("Please login to gmail first")
    }
}
```

Of course, this code does what you asked, but it doesn't handle the case where the user clicks on the button, was logged in, then logs out at some future point and clicks the button again. The localStorage value wouldn't have been reset in that case, unless you do it elsewhere.

Comment: Hi mordred, 
i have already have this logic. But i stuck with browser action in chrome. I will update my code there